# machine learning algorithms vs GIS/Remote Sensing Softwares algorithms

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, gis

Are the classification algorithms in GIS/Remote Sensing Softwares also machine learning algorithms? if no, what is the difference?

Comment: This is a very broad question as the 'algorithms in GIS/Remote Sensing' software is too vague. What algorithms are you specifically asking about?

Comment: I am asking about Maximum Likelihood, SVM, Random Forest, IsoData, K-means!!! I mean if they are available in GIS/Remote sensing softwares and are called parametric methods why the same algorithms in statistical softwares (Python, R) are called Machine Learning algorithms (non parametrics)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, classic GIS/RS algorithms do not fall under the term machine learning, because classification criteria is still user-picked. Machine learning algorithms not only set the classification thresholds by themselves but also look for useful classification criteria on their own.

Keep in mind that I might be wrong as this is just my understanding of things :)